# I want to compare values of two files csv or txt

Tags: python, file, csv

I want to compare two values in the file like both files have age variable. If age in file1 has constant value 16 and should compare with file2 age in interval 15-20 to meet a condition true.

So far tried this. It compares the lines but I need to compare the age interval like in file1 Age is 15 so should compare to file2 Age from 15-20.

```
     filename1 = "/home/pi/desktop/detect.txt"
     filename2 = "/media/pi/KINGSTON/config.txt"


     with open(filename1) as f1:
        with open(filename2) as f2:
           file1list = f1.read().splitlines()
           file2list = f2.read().splitlines()
           list1length = len(file1list)
           list2length = len(file2list)
           if list1length == list2length:
               for index in range(len(file1list)):
                   if file1list[index] == file2list[index]:
                       print(file1list[index] + "==" + file2list[index])
                   else:                  
                       print(file1list[index] + "!=" + file2list[index]+" Not
                                                                   Equel")
            else:
                print("difference inthe size of the file and number of 
                                                                   lines")
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Do you have your sample code written up to a certain level?!

Comment: Please check the code I used to compare output by lines of the files.

Comment: I'd suggest including some lines of each file (or make up data that shares relevant details with the real data)

Answer (score 0):

You would need to grab each value from the corresponding files and compare them.

[Here](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/reading-csv-files) is a link on how to read values from .csv files using Python, and [here](https://www.101computing.net/python-reading-a-text-file/) is link on how to read values from a .txt file. If you are storing just a singular value in two separate text files, then you can simply use Python's open() and read() functions like this:

```
file = open('filename','r')
file_contents = file.read()
```

[Here's](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_file_open.asp) another link for more info on the .read() function.

Please provide more information and context when you ask a question next time so we can provide better answers :).

Comment: @Shadabkhan what outputs are you getting? Also, I'm not sure if it's just the way you've posted your code, but there are many indenting errors there.

Comment: I removed the indentation error. This code is comparing two txt files perfectly with lines. But My problem is to compare between two values.

Comment: How is your text file structured? Can you post an example?